Why does "Read the Fine Print" say that a quantum computer can "maybe" achieve a modest speedup for optimization problems?
Quantum Machine Learning Algorithms: Read the Fine Print says:

By using a quantum computer,
one could dramatically accelerate the simulation of quantum physics and chemistry (the original application
advocated by Richard Feynman in the 1980s); break almost all of the public-key cryptography currently used
on the Internet (for example, by quickly factoring large numbers, with the famous Shor’s algorithm);
and maybe achieve a modest speedup for solving optimization problems in the infamous “NP-hard” class
(but no one is sure about the last one).

Why is no one sure about the last point? Don't quantum computers achieve polynomial speed-ups for Circuit-SAT, an NP-hard problem that some optimization problems can be translated to?

Maybe Aaronson didn’t want to dismiss the possibility that BPP=BQP? Or maybe he was concerned about the dramatic overhead Grover needs  for real world optimization problems? He had a blog post about it… maybe it’s addressed there. Circuit SAT isn’t really an NPO problem I guess. The reductions of CircuitSAT to hard NPO problems don’t always keep the square-root speedup I think.

If BPP=BQP, that means the other applications he's listed, simulating quantum physics and breaking public-key cryptography won't need quantum computers, which doesn't seem to be what he's saying. The only blog post I can find related to this question is the one where he says indeed that grover's algorithm will give a speed up for optimization problems https://scottaaronson.blog/?p=7143. Would you happen to have an example for the claim that reductions to Circuit-SAT kill square-root speedups?

I'd also point to these lecture notes....  He states "So then
the question becomes a subtle one, of whether Grover’s algorithm can be combined with the best classical tricks that we know, to achieve a polynomial speedup even compared to a classical computer that uses the same tricks. For many NP​-complete problems, the answer seems to be yes, but it need not be yes for all of them". (Emphasis added). To be fair, Ambainis does give a $\sqrt N$ speedup even for the more structured 3SAT (but there's a polynomial factor there too).

To avoid the contradiction between the "Read the Fine Print" statement and the lecture notes, it seems like we have to interpret the "Read the Fine Print" statement as saying that no one is sure if quantum computers will achieve a modest speedup for all optimization problems but we are pretty sure that they will achieve a speedup for some of them. Does this sound like the appropriate interpretation?

Yeah I think that's consistent with what I understand (and what Aaronson was trying to get to with his lecture notes and his article.)

@MarkSpinelli Your "Maybe Aaronson didn’t want to dismiss the possibility that BPP=BQP?" turned out to be right. There's a missing extra "maybe" in that sentence that would make this "BPP=BQP" possibility clear.

I reached out to the author. Here's how I would rephrase this sentence based on our correspondence:

By using a quantum computer, one could break almost all of the public-key cryptography currently used on the Internet (for example, by quickly factoring large numbers, with the famous Shor’s algorithm); maybe dramatically accelerate the simulation of quantum physics and chemistry (the original application advocated by Richard Feynman in the 1980s);  and maybe achieve a modest speedup for solving optimization problems in the infamous “NP-hard” class (but no one is sure about the last two).

With the rephrasing, the sentence makes it clear that's it's not claiming that there is a quantum speedup for factoring. It also doesn't deny that it might turn out that simulating quantum physics and solving optimizations problems can be done classically. Quantum simulation and Grover based algorithms have to be evaluated on a case-by-case basis against the best classical algorithms.


Why is no one sure about the last point? Don't quantum computers achieve polynomial speed-ups for [Circuit-SAT], an NP-hard problem that some optimization problems can be translated to?

Theoretically, Grover's algorithm solves CIRCUIT-SAT problem quadratically faster than the best-known classical algorithm.
Practically, the overhead introduced by error correction introduces large constant factor that would cancel out this speedup. See for example this paper.
Of course, this could change by enhancing the hardware to be less error-prone and developing error-correction methods with less overhead.
